# LinearLayout with dynamic child views OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I have a ListView. Every ListViewItem is mainly a LinearLayout with different number of images. So when I am reusing ListViewItem I call

```
mediaLinear.RemoveAllViewsInlayout();
```

And then foreach data entry I am inserting new ImageView like so:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.From (_context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.PostsListItem, null);
    }
    ...
    LinearLayout mediaLinear = convertView.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.post_media);
    mediaLinear.RemoveAllViewsInLayout ();
    var ats = DBWorker.Instance.Connection.Table<Core.Local.Attachment> ().Where (...);
    foreach (var att in ats.ToListAsync().Result) {
        var im = new ImageView (_context); //exception here
        _memoryCache.SetImage (_context, im, att.url, MainActivity.TempFolder).ConfigureAwait(false);
        mediaLinear.AddView (im);
    }
    ...
    return convertView;
}
```

How to properly solve this problem?

```
 [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 45(1728B) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.368ms total 13.142ms
    no cache for item
    55868 Childs count: 1
   ......
    [art]   native: #36 pc 000ad117  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com-1@base.apk@classes.dex (Java_md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9_PostsListViewAdapter_n_1getView__ILandroid_view_View_2Landroid_view_ViewGroup_2+187)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.n_getView(Native method)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.getView(PostsListViewAdapter.java:46)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4539)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    [art]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    [art]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    [Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xf3fca100] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xd9adde80]: 3
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 569us total 11.319ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 626us total 17.213ms
    [art] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 20B allocation
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 537us total 15.912ms
    [art] Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 20 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM"
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.183ms total 13.635ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 968us total 18.755ms
    [art] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 28B allocation
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.653ms total 17.441ms
    [art] Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM" (recursive case)
    [art] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    [art]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x739e6000 self=0xf3c25800
    [art]   | sysTid=16583 nice=-6 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf7711ea0
    [art]   | state=R schedstat=( 51640943258 3602210510 26084 ) utm=3430 stm=1733 core=2 HZ=100
    [art]   | stack=0xff04c000-0xff04e000 stackSize=8MB
    [art]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    [art]   at android.view.View.toString(View.java:4250)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.n_getView(Native method)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.getView(PostsListViewAdapter.java:46)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4539)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    [art]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    [art]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    [art] Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 5.480ms total 7.922ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.134ms total 16.326ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 892us total 17.164ms
    [art] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 20B allocation
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.042ms total 17.104ms
    [art] Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 20 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM"
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.701ms total 16.814ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.728ms total 17.024ms
    [art] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 28B allocation
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 643us total 17.888ms
    [art] Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM" (recursive case)
    [art] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    [art]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x739e6000 self=0xf3c25800
    [art]   | sysTid=16583 nice=-6 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf7711ea0
    [art]   | state=R schedstat=( 51750576514 3606256916 26097 ) utm=3438 stm=1736 core=3 HZ=100
    [art]   | stack=0xff04c000-0xff04e000 stackSize=8MB
    [art]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    [art]   at android.view.View.toString(View.java:4250)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.n_getView(Native method)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.getView(PostsListViewAdapter.java:46)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4539)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    [art]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    [art]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 592us total 13.027ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 844us total 16.250ms
    [art] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 52B allocation
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 619us total 15.621ms
    [art] Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 52 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM"
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 600us total 10.853ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 920us total 16.905ms
    [art] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 28B allocation
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.314ms total 15.773ms
    [art] Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM" (recursive case)
    [art] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    [art]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x739e6000 self=0xf3c25800
    [art]   | sysTid=16583 nice=-6 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf7711ea0
    [art]   | state=R schedstat=( 51849796865 3607688955 26109 ) utm=3447 stm=1737 core=3 HZ=100
    [art]   | stack=0xff04c000-0xff04e000 stackSize=8MB
    [art]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    [art]   native: #00 pc 00005d03  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+83)
    [art]   native: #01 pc 00003051  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+33)
    [art]   native: #02 pc 003c9b97  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+135)
    [art]   native: #03 pc 0038f2c2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+290)
    [art]   native: #04 pc 00395bdb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+459)
    [art]   native: #05 pc 001f1efb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+1243)
    [art]   native: #06 pc 001f5ba5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, art::mirror::Class**)+2773)
    [art]   native: #07 pc 0017e1bb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Class::AllocObject(art::Thread*)+1275)
    [art]   native: #08 pc 00394dd4  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowNewWrappedException(art::ThrowLocation const&, char const*, char const*)+820)
    [art]   native: #09 pc 00395c82  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+626)
    [art]   native: #10 pc 001f1efb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+1243)
    [art]   native: #11 pc 001f5ba5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, art::mirror::Class**)+2773)
    [art]   native: #12 pc 0031eed3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::String::Alloc(art::Thread*, int)+1955)
    [art]   native: #13 pc 0031f39d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::String::AllocFromUtf16(art::Thread*, int, unsigned short const*, int)+45)
    [art]   native: #14 pc 002cb4cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+363)
    [art]   native: #15 pc 0010ec4d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+125)
    [art]   native: #16 pc 00005eb7   (???)
    [art]   native: #17 pc 000048a2   (???)
    [art]   native: #18 pc 00004107   (???)
    [art]   native: #19 pc 00003c8f   (???)
    [art]   native: #20 pc 00003b77   (???)
    [art]   native: #21 pc 00007bd7   (???)
    [art]   native: #22 pc 000079fb   (???)
    [art]   native: #23 pc 0000751b   (???)
    [art]   native: #24 pc 0000724d   (???)
    [art]   native: #25 pc 00007354   (???)
    [art]   native: #26 pc 0002a834  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #27 pc 001b22cb  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (mono_runtime_invoke+75)
    [art]   native: #28 pc 000e19bc  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #29 pc 000e2328  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #30 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #31 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #32 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #33 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #34 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #35 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #36 pc 000e34f9  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #37 pc 000f0000  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #38 pc 00007023   (???)
    [art]   native: #39 pc 00006fc7   (???)
    [art]   native: #40 pc 0003134b   (???)
    [art]   native: #41 pc 0000df1f   (???)
    [art]   native: #42 pc 000ad117  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com@base.apk@classes.dex (Java_md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9_PostsListViewAdapter_n_1getView__ILandroid_view_View_2Landroid_view_ViewGroup_2+187)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.n_getView(Native method)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.getView(PostsListViewAdapter.java:46)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4539)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    [art]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    [art]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.288ms total 11.770ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.475ms total 18.088ms
    [art] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 52B allocation
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 881us total 16.762ms
    [art] Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 52 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM"
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 10.729ms total 22.730ms
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 650us total 47.875ms
    [art] Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 28B allocation
    [art] Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
    [art] Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 1.204ms total 23.964ms
    [art] Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 28 byte allocation with 16 free bytes and 16B until OOM" (recursive case)
    [art] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    [art]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x739e6000 self=0xf3c25800
    [art]   | sysTid=16583 nice=-6 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf7711ea0
    [art]   | state=R schedstat=( 52007888965 3621142086 26132 ) utm=3455 stm=1744 core=3 HZ=100
    [art]   | stack=0xff04c000-0xff04e000 stackSize=8MB
    [art]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    [art]   native: #00 pc 00005d03  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+83)
    [art]   native: #01 pc 00003051  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+33)
    [art]   native: #02 pc 003c9b97  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+135)
    [art]   native: #03 pc 0038f2c2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+290)
    [art]   native: #04 pc 00395bdb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+459)
    [art]   native: #05 pc 001f1efb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+1243)
    [art]   native: #06 pc 001f5ba5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, art::mirror::Class**)+2773)
    [art]   native: #07 pc 0017e1bb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Class::AllocObject(art::Thread*)+1275)
    [art]   native: #08 pc 00394dd4  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowNewWrappedException(art::ThrowLocation const&, char const*, char const*)+820)
    [art]   native: #09 pc 00395c82  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(char const*)+626)
    [art]   native: #10 pc 001f1efb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ThrowOutOfMemoryError(art::Thread*, unsigned int, art::gc::AllocatorType)+1243)
    [art]   native: #11 pc 001f5ba5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::AllocateInternalWithGc(art::Thread*, art::gc::AllocatorType, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, art::mirror::Class**)+2773)
    [art]   native: #12 pc 0031eed3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::String::Alloc(art::Thread*, int)+1955)
    [art]   native: #13 pc 0031f39d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::String::AllocFromUtf16(art::Thread*, int, unsigned short const*, int)+45)
    [art]   native: #14 pc 002cb4cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+363)
    [art]   native: #15 pc 0010ec4d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+125)
    [art]   native: #16 pc 00005eb7   (???)
    [art]   native: #17 pc 000048a2   (???)
    [art]   native: #18 pc 00004107   (???)
    [art]   native: #19 pc 00003c8f   (???)
    [art]   native: #20 pc 00003b77   (???)
    [art]   native: #21 pc 00007bd7   (???)
    [art]   native: #22 pc 000079fb   (???)
    [art]   native: #23 pc 0000751b   (???)
    [art]   native: #24 pc 00007e74   (???)
    [art]   native: #25 pc 0002a834  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #26 pc 001b22cb  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (mono_runtime_invoke+75)
    [art]   native: #27 pc 000e19bc  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #28 pc 000e2328  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #29 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #30 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #31 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #32 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #33 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #34 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #35 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #36 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #37 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #38 pc 000e24aa  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #39 pc 000e34f9  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #40 pc 000f0000  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so (???)
    [art]   native: #41 pc 00007023   (???)
    [art]   native: #42 pc 00006fc7   (???)
    [art]   native: #43 pc 0003134b   (???)
    [art]   native: #44 pc 0000df1f   (???)
    [art]   native: #45 pc 000ad117  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com@base.apk@classes.dex (Java_md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9_PostsListViewAdapter_n_1getView__ILandroid_view_View_2Landroid_view_ViewGroup_2+187)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.n_getView(Native method)
    [art]   at md51390a9bb27ae81984ed2b5a51b13bec9.PostsListViewAdapter.getView(PostsListViewAdapter.java:46)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:732)
    [art]   at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:671)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4991)
    [art]   at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4539)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    [art]   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    [art]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    [art]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    [art]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    [art]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    [art]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #14
    [Mono] [0xeecaef80] worker finishing
    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #21
    [Mono] [0xd92e8500] worker finishing
    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #19
    [Mono] [0xd92e8280] worker finishing
    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #23
    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #9
    [Mono] [0xdace7600] worker finishing
```

[image]

```
public async Task SetImage (Activity activity, ImageView view, string url, string imagesDirectory)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Get (url);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        string file = System.IO.Path.Combine (imagesDirectory, Helper.ImageNameFromUrl(url));
        if (System.IO.File.Exists (file)) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
            options.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (file, options);
        } else {
            bitmap = await WebWorker.DownloadImage (url);
            SdWorker.SaveBitmap (bitmap, file);
        }
        Console.WriteLine ("no cache for item");
        Put (url, bitmap);
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine (url + " fetched from cache");
    }

    activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
        view.SetImageBitmap (bitmap);
    });
}
```

Comment: How large are the loaded images? If they are too big, you have to do some extra work

Comment: @Sven-Michael Stübe , about 130x97 pixels. I don't think it's a problem, because I am using LRU cache.

Comment: 130x97 display size or size of the actual image file. Which Image cache implementation are you using? Something own or a library?

Comment: Can you post the OOM exception that you get? You can also increase the heap size via `android:largeHeap="true"`. Finally you can use Allocation Tracker to see some statistics: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc

Comment: @Sven-Michael Stübe, actual size. I am using code from here http://www.mobtowers.com/xamarin-android-image-caching/

Comment: @Jon Douglas , updated question. can't post full output. full output here http://rghost.ru/87sXK4cxc (press blue button to download)

Comment: @Sven-Michael Stübe, added code for SetImage method.

Comment: Maybe problem is that too many async tasks are created during user's scroll? (SetImage method is async)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would have you look into Implementing the ViewHolder pattern. You can read more about it here https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/
Basically it helps to speed up your listview so by reusing cells in your listview

Once that is done I would remove any async operations from your GetView. GetView is called every time a cell is about to become visible. So any computation heavy actions on the UI thread here will slow things down a lot.

Lastly I would attempt to manually dispose of all the images.By looping through the children.

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  MyViewHolder holder;
  var view = convertView;

  if(view != null) 
    holder = view.Tag as MyViewHolder;


  if (holder == null) {
    holder = new MyViewHolder ();
    view = LayoutInflater.From (_context).Inflate (Resource.Layout.PostsListItem, null);
    holder.MediaLinear = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.post_media);
    view.Tag = holder;
  } 

  LoadViewHolderImages(holder);

  return view;
}

async Task LoadViewHolderImages(MyViewHolder holder)
{
    CleanupImageViewHolder(holder);
    var ats = await DBWorker.Instance.Connection.Table<Core.Local.Attachment> ().Where (...).ToListAsync();
    foreach (var att in ats {
        var im = new ImageView (_context); //exception here
        await _memoryCache.SetImage (_context, im, att.url, MainActivity.TempFolder);
        mediaLinear.AddView (im);
    }
}


void CleanupImageViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder)
{
    // Lets Manually dispose of all children images
    for (int i = 0; i < holder.MediaLinear.ChildCount; i++) {
        var view = holder.MediaLinear.GetChildAt (i) as ImageView;
        if (view != null) {
            view.Dispose();
        }
    }
    holder.MediaLinear.RemoveAllViewsInLayout ();
}
```

Comment: I quickly tried your solution with manually disposing LinearLayout's childs at demo project and it seems working. I was watching heap size in android device monitor and saw that heap size decreases sometimes (before your solution it was only increasing). I'll try your solution on working project and then will leave a comment again. Many thanks)